# Quando uso uma classe "Endpoint" para publicar um Web Service, aonde o WSDL é criado?

Tags: java, web-service, soap, wsdl, jax-ws

Por exemplo, eu tenho 3 classes no meu Web Service:

1 - Uma SEI (a interface do Web Service):

```
package calc;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding;
import javax.jws.soap.SOAPBinding.Style;

@WebService
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.RPC)
public interface CalculatorServer {
    @WebMethod float sum(float num1, float num2);
    @WebMethod float subtraction(float num1, float num2);
    @WebMethod float multiplication(float num1, float num2);
    @WebMethod float division(float num1, float num2);
}
```

2 - Uma SIB (a implementação da Interface):

```
package calc;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "calc.CalculatorServer")
public class CalculatorServerImpl implements CalculadoraServer {

    public float sum(float num1, float num2) {
        return num1 + num2;
    }

    public float subtraction(float num1, float num2) {
        return num1 - num2;
    }

...

}
```

3 - E a classe responsável por publicá-la:

```
package calc;

import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;

public class CalculadoraServerPublisher {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Endpoint.publish("http://127.0.0.1:9876/calc",
        new CalculadoraServerImpl());
    }
}
```

Se eu rodar a terceira classe e acessar o endereço:

```
http://127.0.0.1:9876/calc?wsdl
```

Eu verei o WSDL do meu Web Service. Daí vem a pergunta: se eu posso acessá-lo, ele está fisicamente alocado em algum lugar do meu computador, mas...AONDE? Eu tentei usar todas as ferramentas de busca do Windows que eu conheço (eu uso o Windows 8.1) e nenhuma delas conseguiu encontrar. Aonde ele está, afinal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Daí vem a pergunta: se eu posso acessá-lo, ele está fisicamente alocado em algum lugar do meu computador, mas...AONDE?

Não é verdade que se você está acessando algum recurso ele necessariamente precisa ser físico e estar em algum lugar do computador. O caso apresentado por você é um destes cenários, já que o WSDL é armazendo em memória (não o WSDL exatamente, mas o que o forma).

Com JAX-RS, se não informarmos a localização do WSDL ele é gerado automaticamente. Na especificação do JAX-WS (considerando a 2.2), temos o seguinte em `5.2.2 Publicação`:

> The WSDL contract for an endpoint is created dynamically based on the annotations on the implementor
>   class, the Binding in use and the set of metadata documents specified on the endpoint (see 5.2.4)

Ou seja, o WSDL é criado dinamicamente e é criado o metadado dos endpoints baseado nas anotações. No entanto na especificação não há nada que fale *COMO* estes artefatos devem ser armazenados.

Cada implementação da especificação armazena o WSDL de uma forma, então para saber detalhes de **ONDE** é armazenado, é necessário ver como cada implementação realiza esta tarefa, mas como já se tem os metadados é comum que ele esteja em memória em algum objeto e é serializado sempre que as URL terminadas em `?wsdl` ou `?WSDL` é chamada.

Você pode olhar com detalhes a especificação do JAX-WS disponível em https://jax-ws.java.net/, os tópicos **5.2.4** e **5.2.5** possuem informações relevantes, além da documentação de implementações do JAX-WS que atendem à estes pontos da especificação, como por exemplo olhar as classes dos pacotes `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport` e `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl`, do JDK, para ver como as referências são armazenadas para serialização.